# Кaк залить область цветом?

Tags: java, swing

Создаю графический редактор на Java.

Как реализовать заливку области цветом? Написал функцию,которая заносит в массив координаты,а потом образует фигуру,но она не работает.

Код:

```
public Polygon FloodFill (BufferedImage ima,Point node, Color fillcolor, int Oldcolor){             
         Point a [] = new Point[1000];
         Point n;
         n=node; 
         int x = n.x;
         int y = n.y;
         int i=0;
         while(a[i]!=null){                         
             if(ima.getRGB(x, y)==oldcolor){
                 a[i]=n; }

             if(ima.getRGB(x-1, y)==oldcolor){
                 n.setLocation(x-1, y);
                 a[i+1]=n;}

            if(ima.getRGB(x+1, y)==oldcolor){                   
                n.setLocation(x+1, y);
                a[i+2]=n;}

            if(ima.getRGB(x, y-1)==oldcolor){                   
                n.setLocation(x, y-1);
                a[i+3]=n;}

            if(ima.getRGB(x, y+1)==oldcolor){                   
                n.setLocation(x, y+1);
                a[i+4]=n;}  
            i=i+1;
                       }
         int yMas [] = new int[1000];
         int xMas [] = new int[1000];
         int d=0;
         for(i=0;a[i]!=null;i++){
             yMas[i]=a[i].x;
             xMas[i]=a[i].y;
             d=d+1;
         }
         Polygon poly = new Polygon(xMas, yMas, d);            
 return poly;}
```

Вот так вызываю функцию:

```
Polygon p; p = FloodFill(imag,n,maincolor,oldcolor);  
           g2.fillPolygon(p);
```

Comment: вы используете swing?

Comment: да,Swing и AWT.

Answer (score 1):

Функция заливки известной фигуры в swing реализовано через метод **fill**

```
g2D.fill(Shape s)
```

Соответственно вам необходимо самостоятельно определить фигуру, создать её и заполнить её методом fill.
 Определить свою фигуру можно сравнивая цвет рядом стоящих пикселей с белым (если ваш фон конечно белый), и запоминая их.В конце образуя их в фигуру.

Comment: Спасибо,но объясните пожалуйста по подробней как определить фигуру. То есть мне нужно сначала получить цвет точки в которой находится мышка /*'x=e.getX(); y=e.getY();*/ Потом нужно найти цвет этой точки 'col.getRGB(x, y);' А как потом сравнить цвета рядом стоящих пикселей с полученным и образовать фигуру?

Comment: @Kires Необходимо задать цикл while, который будет выполнятся пока рядом есть белый пиксель. Проверять нужно точки (x+1;y)(x-1;y)(x;y+1)(x;y-1). Забивать точки в массив, и у новых полученных точек спрашивать тоже условие. Образовать фигуру можно этим массивом отсортировав его по x, потом по y, И по всем точкам нарисовать g2D.fillPoligon(p);